# html row selection change with up/down key in j query

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have html table like :

[image]

Now I want to change row selection with up/down key & as well as scroll in j query/ java script . 
Any one tell me how can it possible!

Comment: It's possible. What have you tried?

Comment: I have no idea. Just try to do it!

Comment: @csefaruk check this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/hYCpJ/

Comment: i guess it is possible by row index!

Comment: @csefaruk pls post ur working html code and javascript,then only others can work on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
                switch (event.keyCode) {
                    case 38: /*Function for selecting when arroup*/ break;
                    case 40: /*Function for selecting when arrowdown*/ break;
                }
            });
```

Do you mean something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
<table data-active="1">
    <tr><td>line<td/></tr>
    <tr><td>line<td/></tr>
    <tr><td>line<td/></tr>
    <tr><td>line<td/></tr>
<table>​
```

and js:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
var table = $('table');
if(e.keyCode == 40)
{
    $('table tr:not(:nth-child(' + table.data('active') + '))').css('color','black');
    $('table tr:nth-child(' + table.data('active') + ')').css('color','red');
    table.data('active', table.data('active') + 1);
}
});
```

Then change to hadle other keys, cycle behaviour etc.